# wx python draw arc and circle

Tags: wxpython, automatic-ref-counting, draw

I am using wx python to draw a gauge. And I use drawarc and drawCircle. 
But the result is not as I expected. The arc and the circle are not precisely draw and looks ugly. [GaugeImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3gXQ.png)

```
                pen = wx.Pen(wx.WHITE,2)
                dc.SetPen(pen)
                xFullCoordinate = (x + (OutsideRadius * math.cos((0.5 * math.pi) + (FullDeg * math.pi * newValue)/((MaxValue - MinValue) * 180))))
                yFullCoordinate = (y + (OutsideRadius * math.sin((0.5 * math.pi) + (FullDeg * math.pi * newValue)/((MaxValue - MinValue) * 180))))
                xStartCoodrinate = (x + (OutsideRadius * math.cos((0.5 * math.pi) + (StartDeg * math.pi) / 180)))
                yStartCoodrinate = (y + (OutsideRadius * math.sin((0.5 * math.pi) + (StartDeg * math.pi) / 180)))
                dc.DrawArc((xFullCoordinate,yFullCoordinate),(xStartCoodrinate,yStartCoodrinate),(x, y))
                dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush((48,100,175)))
                dc.DrawCircle(x, y, InsideRadius)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `wx.GraphicsContext` on top of the DC you are currently using. See [in wxPython Phoenix docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.GraphicsContext.html) to see how. Drawing on the GraphicsContext will give nice antialiased graphics. Be advised that the drawing commands may be slightly different for the `GraphicsContext`.

Comment: `wx.GCDC` would a good way to transition the code to use graphics contexts.  It implements a `wx.DC` API on top of a `wx.GraphicsContext`.

Comment: @RobinDunn: I did not mention ``GCDC`` because I had trouble using it in wxPython classic (found it difficult to put a GCDC on top of an existing DC), but good point!